# Renaming sequential image files with gaps

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to rename a list of image files with gaps to be sequential. Also I want to give them a padding of 4. I'm currently using Python 2.7 and Linux bash to program this.

```
    Example:

    1.png
    2.png
    3.png
    20.png
    21.png
    50.png
```

Should turn into:

```
    0001.png
    0002.png
    0003.png
    0004.png
    0005.png
    0006.png
```

I also would like for the files name to be the same as the directory that they are currently in.

```
    Example:

    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0001.png
    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0002.png
    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0003.png
    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0004.png
    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0005.png
    c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0006.png
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Cheers

Comment: What should be the contents of file '0004.png'? Empty file? Copy of '0003.png'?

Comment: 4 = 20.png I think :P  (is that a comment on WA & CO ?)

Comment: How do you want to call this script?  Are you going to pass a folder or the filenames or the full paths of all of the files or... ???  The solution is different for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is python

```
#first collect all files that start with a number and end with .png
my_files = [f for f in os.listdir(some_directory) if f[0].isdigit() and f.endswith(".png")]
#sort them based on the number  
sorted_files = sorted(my_files,key=lambda x:int(x.split(".")[0])) # sort the file names by starting number
#rename them sequentially
for i,fn in enumerate(sorted_files,1): #thanks wim
    os.rename(sorted_files[i],"{0:04d}.png".format(i))
```

I could have used `list.sort(key=...)` to sort in place but I figured this would be marginally more verbose and readable ...

Comment: better is `for i, fn in enumerate(sorted_files, 1)`.  With your current code you will have index error at the end of the range, and miss the first file.

Comment: oh cool i didnt know about being able to offset enumerate like that ... and your right stupid oversight on my part (edited accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

**Try doing this** in a shell :

```
rename -n '
    $s = substr(join("_", split("/", $ENV{PWD})), 1) . ".";
    s/(\d+)\.png/$s . sprintf("%04d", ++$c) . ".png"/e
' *.png
```

**Output** :

```
1.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0001.png
2.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0002.png
3.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0003.png
20.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0004.png
21.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0005.png
50.png -> c_users_johnny_desktop_images.0006.png
```

`rename` is http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/ and is the defalut `rename` command on many distros.

When the command is tested as well, you can remove the `-n` switch to do it for real.

Comment: 1337 bashing ... much shorter than my python :P ... cept I dont think its what OP wants ... this just reformats the number to be 4 wide ... he wants them sequential from 0001 ... 000n

Answer (score 0):

Blah Blah Blah.  CSH is bad.  BASH is good.  Python is better.  Bah humbug.  I still use TCSH...

```
% set i = 1
% foreach FILE ( `ls *[0-9].png | sort -n` )
    echo mv $FILE `printf %04d $i`.png ; @ i ++
    end
```

Output:

```
mv 1.png 0001.png
mv 2.png 0002.png
mv 3.png 0003.png
mv 20.png 0004.png
mv 21.png 0005.png
mv 50.png 0006.png
```

---

---

**Responding to comments:**

*Still need c_users_johnny_desktop_images.*

Ok, so use:

```
echo mv $FILE c_users_johnny_desktop_images.`printf %04d $i`.png ; @ i ++
```

It's not like my example was hard to read.

Correction:  Perhaps you meant to automatically extract the current directory name and incorporate it.  E.g.:

```
echo mv $FILE `echo $cwd | sed -e 's|^/||' -e 's|/|_|g'`.`printf %04d $i`.png ; @ i ++
```

-

*are globs not present in tcsh ? Your parsing of ls seems scary*

Of course globs are present.  That's what we are passing into **ls**.  But globbing gives us a list that is sorted alphabetically, as in 1,2,20,21,3,50.  We want a numerical sort, as in 1,2,3,20,21,50.  Standard problem when we don't have leading zeros in the numbers.

**sort -n** does a numeric sort.  **ls** gives us a newline after each filename.  We could just as easily write:

```
foreach FILE ( `echo *[0-9].png | tr ' ' '\012' | sort -n` )
```

But I'm lazy and **ls** does the newline for me.  What's so scary about it?

Comment: Still need `c_users_johnny_desktop_images.` part of each destination files. Moreover, are `glob`s not present in `tcsh` ? Your parsing of `ls` seems scary =)

Comment: Original post amended to respond more thoroughly.